# Spring MVC - Returning JSON Object with List<Custom> property

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I have the following mapping on my spring mvc controller:

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/servers", method = RequestMethod.GET)

    public @ResponseBody Server getServers(@RequestParam(value="password", required=false) String password)
    {

        Server server = new Server();
        server.setIpaddress("192.168.0.4");
        server.setServername("serverOne");

        List<Service> list = new ArrayList<Service>();   

        Service s1 = new Service();
        s1.setServiceName("telnet");
        s1.setServicePort(21);
        list.add(s1);
        s1= new Service();
        s1.setServiceName("SSH");
        s1.setServicePort(22);
        list.add(s1);

        server.SetServices(list);
        return server;

    }
```

It should return a server class in json , with one filled property matching List
but is doesn't show anything. This are the involved classes:

Class Server:

```
package es.landesoft.mvctesting.JavaBeans;

import java.util.List;


public class Server {


    private String ipaddress;
    private String serverName;
    private List<Service> services;

    public void setIpaddress(String value)
    {
        this.ipaddress = value;     
    }

    public String getIpAddress()
    {
        return this.ipaddress;  
    }

    public void setServername (String value)
    {       
        this.serverName= value;
    }

    public String getServername()
    {
        return this.serverName;     
    }

    public void SetServices(List<Service> services)
    {
        this.services= services;
    }

    public List<Service> GetServices()
    {
        return this.services;
    }

}
```

Class service:

```
package es.landesoft.mvctesting.JavaBeans;

public class Service
{
    private String serviceName;
    private int servicePort;

    public void setServiceName(String value)
    {
        this.serviceName= value;
    }

    public String getServiceName(){
        return this.serviceName;
    }

    public void setServicePort(int value)
    {
        this.servicePort=value;
    }

    public int getServicePort()
    {
        return this.servicePort;
    }

}
```

The Json Output is:

> {"servername":"serverOne","ipAddress":"192.168.0.4"}

No trace of the List property. 
What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do like this

Change your Server  model like this.

```
public class Server {

   private List<Service> services = new ArrayList<Service>();
}
```

And Add like this.

```
Server server = new Server();
server.setIpaddress("192.168.0.4");
server.setServername("serverOne");
Service s1 = new Service();
s1.setServiceName("telnet");
s1.setServicePort(21); 
server.GetServices().add(s1); //Add like this.
```

Note: Maintain the java naming conventions.

```
 public List<Service> GetServices(){}
```

should be  `public List<Service> getServices()`

The same for setters too.

Comment: The output is now: {"services":[{"serviceName":"telnet","servicePort":21},{"serviceName":"SSH","servicePort":22}],"ipAddress":"192.168.0.4","servername":"serverOne"}. So working perfectly. As .net developer I'm starting to love learning Java. Thank you verymuch. One little question. Is there any way of ordering the output?. Services at the end?

Comment: Ok I found it-> JsonPropertyOrder